# Как построить рамку вокруг нескольких форм в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qgroupbox

Имеется программа с `label` и формами `qlineedit` для ввода текста.

Ниже слева представлена фотография программы и справа фотография программы, с подрисованной в `Paint'е` рамкой (собственно нужно сделать как на правой картинке):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я знаю как добавить рамку для простого `label` с текстом, но вот как добавить её для `label` + `qlineedit` не знаю... Помогите, пожалуйста. Ниже представляю код программы:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, \
    QRadioButton, QButtonGroup, QMessageBox, QApplication, QLineEdit, QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QIcon, QPixmap

WINDOW_HEIGHT = 450
WINDOW_WIDTH = 300
WINDOW_NAME = 'КВУР'
WINDOW_ICON_NAME = 'Images\\main_logo.png'


MAIN_FONT = 'Times'
FONT_HEADER_SIZE = 13
FONT_BODY_SIZE = 8


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.create_all_forms()
        self.fill_forms()
        self.create_layers()

    def create_all_forms(self):
        self.heading_label = QLabel()
        self.entering_label = QLabel()

        self.first_value = QLineEdit()
        self.second_value = QLineEdit()
        self.third_value = QLineEdit()

        self.find_button = QPushButton('Найти')
        self.clear_button = QPushButton('Очистить')

    def fill_forms(self):
        self.heading_label.setText('Решение квадратного уравнения')
        self.heading_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE, QFont.Bold))

        self.entering_label.setText('Введите коэффициенты:')
        self.entering_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE))

        self.first_value.setText('Значение 1')
        self.first_value.setFixedSize(265, 20)
        self.second_value.setText('Значение 2')
        self.second_value.setFixedSize(265, 20)
        self.third_value.setText('Значение 3')
        self.third_value.setFixedSize(265, 20)

    def create_layers(self):
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        heading_label = QHBoxLayout()
        heading_label.addWidget(self.heading_label)
        main_layout.addLayout(heading_label)

        entering_label = QHBoxLayout()
        entering_label.addWidget(self.entering_label)
        main_layout.addLayout(entering_label)

        first_qline_edit = QHBoxLayout()
        first_qline_edit.addWidget(self.first_value)
        main_layout.addLayout(first_qline_edit)

        second_qline_edit = QHBoxLayout()
        second_qline_edit.addWidget(self.second_value)
        main_layout.addLayout(second_qline_edit)

        third_qline_edit = QHBoxLayout()
        third_qline_edit.addWidget(self.third_value)
        main_layout.addLayout(third_qline_edit)

        line = QFormLayout()
        line.addRow(self.find_button, self.clear_button)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()
        self.create_and_connect_grid()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        self.setFixedSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        self.setWindowTitle(WINDOW_NAME)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(WINDOW_ICON_NAME))

    def create_and_connect_grid(self):
        self.main_grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        form_builder_object = FormBuilder()
        self.main_grid.addWidget(form_builder_object, 0, 0, Qt.AlignTop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

> Виджет **QGroupBox** предоставляет рамку группового окна с заголовком.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgroupbox.html#details

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout, QGroupBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, \
    QRadioButton, QButtonGroup, QMessageBox, QApplication, QLineEdit, QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QIcon, QPixmap


WINDOW_HEIGHT = 450
WINDOW_WIDTH = 350
WINDOW_NAME = 'КВУР'
WINDOW_ICON_NAME = 'lena-2.png'              # 'Images\\main_logo.png'


MAIN_FONT = 'Times'
FONT_HEADER_SIZE = 13
FONT_BODY_SIZE = 8


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.create_all_forms()
        self.fill_forms()
        self.create_layers()

    def create_all_forms(self):
        self.heading_label = QLabel('Решение квадратного уравнения')
        self.entering_label = QLabel('Введите коэффициенты:')

        self.first_value = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Значение a')
        self.second_value = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Значение b')
        self.third_value = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Значение c')

        self.find_button = QPushButton('Найти')
        self.clear_button = QPushButton('Очистить')

    def fill_forms(self):
        self.heading_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE, QFont.Bold))
        self.heading_label.setStyleSheet('border: 3px solid green; border-radius: 5px;')
        self.entering_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE))

    def create_layers(self):
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.heading_label)

        self.groupBox = QGroupBox(self.entering_label.text())
        self.groupBox.setStyleSheet('''
            QGroupBox {
                margin-top: 2ex;
            }
            QGroupBox:enabled {
                border: 3px solid green;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
            QGroupBox::title {
                subcontrol-origin: margin;
                left: 3ex;
            }
        ''')
        groupBoxLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.groupBox)
        groupBoxLayout.addWidget(self.first_value)
        groupBoxLayout.addWidget(self.second_value)
        groupBoxLayout.addWidget(self.third_value)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        
        line = QHBoxLayout()
        line.addWidget(self.find_button)
        line.addWidget(self.clear_button)
        main_layout.addLayout(line)  


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()
        self.create_and_connect_grid()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        self.setFixedSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        self.setWindowTitle(WINDOW_NAME)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(WINDOW_ICON_NAME))

    def create_and_connect_grid(self):
        self.main_grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        form_builder_object = FormBuilder()
        self.main_grid.addWidget(form_builder_object, 0, 0, Qt.AlignTop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо! У Вас всегда классно получается)

Comment: @GunTHE пожалуйста, у вас тоже скоро будет получаться.